# valgrind for Android devices (Crystax). configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: android, android-ndk, valgrind

Using and adapting the script(https://gist.github.com/smits/27060b310546ca6f76568f24838118c3) I get and error " C compiler cannot create executables":

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#set -x

function extract()
{
     if [ -f "$1" ] ; then
         case "$1" in
             *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf "$1"     ;;
             *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf "$1"     ;;
             *.bz2)       bunzip2 "$1"      ;;
             *.rar)       unrar x "$1"      ;;
             *.gz)        gunzip "$1"       ;;
             *.tar)       tar xvf "$1"      ;;
             *.tbz2)      tar xvjf "$1"     ;;
             *.tgz)       tar xvzf "$1"     ;;
             *.zip)       unzip "$1"        ;;
             *.Z)         uncompress "$1"   ;;
             *.7z)        7z x "$1"         ;;
             *)           echo "$1 cannot be extracted via >extract<" ;;
         esac
     else
         echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
     fi
}

VALGRIND_VERSION="3.15.0"
VALGRIND_EXTENSION=".tar.bz2"
VALGRIND_DIRECTORY="valgrind-${VALGRIND_VERSION}"
VALGRIND_TARBALL="valgrind-${VALGRIND_VERSION}${VALGRIND_EXTENSION}"

# Only download Valgrind tarball again if not already downloaded
if [[ ! -f "${VALGRIND_TARBALL}" ]]; then
  wget -v -nc "https://sourceware.org/pub/valgrind/${VALGRIND_TARBALL}"
fi

# Only extract Valgrind tarball again if not already extracted
if [[ ! -d "$VALGRIND_DIRECTORY" ]]; then
  extract "$VALGRIND_TARBALL"
fi

# Ensure ANDROID_NDK is set
#if [[ ! -z "$ANDROID_NDK" ]]; then
  export ANDROID_NDK="/home/userhome/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1"
#fi

# Ensure ANDOID_SDK_HOME is set
#if [[ ! -z "$ANDROID_SDK" ]]; then
  #export ANDROID_SDK="/opt/android-sdk-linux/"
#fi

if [[ ! -d "$VALGRIND_DIRECTORY" ]];
then
  echo "Problem with extracting Valgrind from $VALGRIND_TARBALL into $VALGRIND_DIRECTORY!!!"
  exit -1
fi

# Move to extracted directory
cd "$VALGRIND_DIRECTORY"

# ARM Toolchain
export PATH=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:$PATH
ARCH_ABI="arm-linux-androideabi-6"
export AR="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export LD="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export CC="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
export CXX="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++"
export RANLIB="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"
export AS="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as"
export CPP="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/${ARCH_ABI}/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-cpp"



echo $ANDROID_NDK
echo $AR
echo $LD
echo $CC
echo $CXX

[[ ! -d "$ANDROID_NDK" || ! -f "$AR" || ! -f "$LD" || ! -f "$CC" || ! -f "$CXX" ]] && echo "Make sure AR, LD, CC, CXX variables are defined correctly. Ensure ANDROID_NDK is defined also" && exit -1

# Configure build
export HWKIND="generic"
ANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21
export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/arch-arm -DANDROID_HARDWARE_$HWKIND"
export CFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/arch-arm"

# BUG: For some reason file command is unable to detect if the file does not exist with ! -f , it says it doesn't exist even when it does!!!
BUILD=true
if [[ "${VALGRIND_DIRECTORY}/Inst/data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind" = *"No such file or directory"* ]]; then
  BUILD=true
fi

if [[ "$BUILD" = true ]];
then
  ./configure --prefix="/data/local/Inst" \
  --host="armv7-unknown-linux" \
  --target="armv7-unknown-linux" \
  --with-tmpdir="/sdcard"

  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Can't configure!" && exit -1

  # Determine the number of jobs (commands) to be run simultaneously by GNU Make
  NO_CPU_CORES=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)

  if [ $NO_CPU_CORES -le 8 ]; then
    JOBS=$(($NO_CPU_CORES+1))
  else
    JOBS=${NO_CPU_CORES}
  fi

  # Compile Valgrind 
  make -j "${JOBS}"

  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Can't compile!" && exit -1

  # Install Valgrind locally
  make -j "${JOBS}" install DESTDIR="$(pwd)/Inst"
  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Can't install!" && exit -1
fi

# Push local Valgrind installtion to the phone
if [[ $(adb shell ls -ld /data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind) = *"No such file or directory"* ]];
then
  adb root
  adb remount
  adb shell "[ ! -d /data/local/Inst ] && mkdir /data/local/Inst"
  adb push Inst /
  adb shell "ls -l /data/local/Inst"

  # Ensure Valgrind on the phone is running
  adb shell "/data/local/Inst/bin/valgrind --version"

  # Add Valgrind executable to PATH (this might fail)
  adb shell "export PATH=$PATH:/data/local/Inst/bin/"
fi
```

I got the following error ( C compiler cannot create executables):

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for armv7-unknown-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for armv7-unknown-linux-gcc... /home/rubvacalz/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/rubvacalz/src/valgrind-3.15.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
Can't configure!
```

And config.log says "error: cannot find -lcrystax":

```
configure:3723: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3745: /home/rubvacalz/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/rubvacalz/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/platforms/android-21/arch-arm --sysroot=/home/rubvacalz/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/platforms/android-21/arch-arm -DANDROID_HARDWARE_yellowstone  conftest.c  >&5
/home/rubvacalz/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/6.1/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: **error: cannot find -lcrystax**
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3749: $? = 1
configure:3787: result: no
configure: failed program was:
```

I don't know if the following includes are required and I don't know if it is included in the script process.

```
-I/home/userhome/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/sources/crystax/include -I/home/userhome/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include -I/home/userhome/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/6/include -I/home/userhome/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -I/home/userhome/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/6/include/backward
```

Comment: valgrind 3.10 is now *really* old (2014). A lot of bug fixes, improvements, support for new hw was added since then.  You should rather compile the latest version.  To compile for android, it might be useful to read README.android in the valgrind distribution.

Comment: Thanks  @phd. I modified the script and add more information. It continues with the same problem because it has an "error: cannot find -lcrystax"

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem. It just add in the script the lines:

export LDFLAGS="-L/home/userhome/src/crystax-ndk-10.3.1/sources/crystax/libs/armeabi-v7a/thumb"

export LIBS="-lcrystax"